# Python: Define boundaries using regular expression

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to replace a word in the string which is read from a parameter using boundaries. But it i am unable to achieve it for parameter value. Below is the code details

```
paramfile=str(Path('C:\\Users\\as15188\\Desktop\\Python\\Param'))+'\\'+'DataStandardization.txt'
 
 with open(paramfile, 'rb') as config_file:
  configs.load(config_file)
 
 filename=str(configs.get((sys.argv[1])+"SourceFile").data)
 tokenfilename=str(configs.get((sys.argv[1])+"TokenFile").data)
 outputfilename=str(configs.get((sys.argv[1])+"OutputFile").data)
 AccountNameColumnNumber=int(configs.get((sys.argv[1])+"AccountNameColumnNumber").data)
 AccountNameColumnNumber -=1
 NextVal=AccountNameColumnNumber+1

  with open(tokenfilename, 'r') as rep_words:
   rep_list = []
   for rep_line in rep_words:
    rep_list.append(tuple(rep_line.strip().split(',')))

  with open(filename, 'r') as old_text:
   with open(outputfilename, 'w') as new_text:
   
    for read_line in old_text:
     new_line = read_line

     Token=new_line.split('|')[3]
     BeforeAttri='|'.join(new_line.split('|')[0:3])
     AfterAttri='|'.join(new_line.split('|')[4:])
 
     for old_word, new_word in rep_list:
      repStr=re.sub(r '\b' old_word '\b', new_word, Token)
      CompValue=BeforeAttri+'|'+repStr+'|'+AfterAttri
    
     new_text.write(CompValue)
```

Below are the parameter values

```
    old_word = Hosp  
    new_word = Hospital   
    Token  = Manor Drug Medical Hosp

Complete Record in file
SourceID|SourceName|AccountName|AddressLine1|AddressLine2|City|State|ZIP5|ZIP4|PhoneNumber|DeltaFlag|MD5  
1|ABC|Manor Drug Medical And Pharma|5795 N 1st St||Fresno|CA|93710|6203|5594314142|A|e6f9b166284831094453ab0a64f855b3
```

Can someone please help in achieving the same
Sample Record-

Comment: Please post the _actual_ code; this one has syntax errors because of missing quotes.

Comment: The posted code is not valid python code. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Thomas i have updated the post with exact code